# Windows security popup first time a user logs in to webserver with windows authentication

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7

Windows Authentication has been enabled on the virtual directory for the website. First time a user logs in with Domain authentication a Windows Security popup window appears. All the user has to do is close it and it won't show up again until a iisreset has been done. The site already have a login screen, so I don't really need that, to be honest, annoying popup. How can I make that popup not show up ever when Windows authentication is enabled?

IIS7 Web server is running on windows 2008 R2 Server.

Comment: Please provide us a example popup printscreen

Comment: If the web app has an authentication/logon function then why do you have any authentication settings configured on the virtual directory? Why don't you just remove that?

Comment: Also, it sounds like the people accessing the website are doing so from machines not joined to the same domain as the web server, or the web server itself isn't joined to a domain. If that's the case then what you're seeing with Windows Authentication is to be expected. The web server doesn't recognize the domain that the machine the user is accessing the website from and so therefore pops up a logon dialog box.